# Samba shows each file several times in the same folder

Tags: debian, windows-7, samba, zfs

I have `Samba 3.5.11 on Debian/kfreebsd sid`. (Also tested with 3.6.1 from experimental)
I have a zfs filesystem `Storage/Photos`.
If I open one the the folders on there (`Storage/Photos/folder1`) it shows (on Windows 7, Total Commander):

- file1.jpg
- file1.jpg
- file2.jpg
- file2.jpg

So I see the same file several times in Total Commander (and Windows Explorer as well).
Sometimes the `Thumbs.db` comes up 20-30 pieces.
I don't know where to start, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Test it with a simpler client first.

On the Debian box, run

`smbclient //server/share`

Enter credentials and run

`ls /your/directory`

Also examine your logs closely.

Comment: The problem comes up only the number of files reaches a limit. 
So I generated a lot of file (190 pieces), in this case on Windows some of them was doubled, alltogether 330 files showed up. With `smbclient` the files are not doubled, but was not in order, I mean I generated the files in sequence, so they sould be in name order on the disk (I suppose).

Comment: what output do you get if you do `dir` on the win7 box on the samba share? 190 files are not so much, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: Strange, if I use `dir` from command line (on Win7) I get the right answer each file once. But if I see the same in Total Commander, or Windows Explorer I got doubling. I made some test, now in my system, the magic number is 135, so if I have 135 or more files in a dir, I get the error, under 135 I don't.